# issue with jquery toggle open/clos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a small pm system and use buttons to toggle the message open or close.
if no message is open the button shows 'lesen' bei click the button it opens the message and the text changes to 'schliessen'. i can open everey message but not close them. than the message close once and opens again but the buttontext than shows still 'lesen'
i hope u understand what i try to explain :) 
here is my code:

this will set the opened message as read in the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setRead($id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "update_pm_status.php",
    data: { id: $id}
   });
}
```

this will open or close the message.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function toggleOpenClose(id) {

 $('#message-'+id).slideToggle("fast");

 if(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML === "lesen") {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "schließen";
} else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "lesen";
}}
```

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<form action="reply.php" method="post">
 <p class="button"> <a class="open-close">
 <div id="container">
<div class="item">
        <span class="toggleOpen" onclick="setRead(this.id); toggleOpenClose(this.id);"      id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="gelesen">lesen</span>
    <div id="message-<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="toggle">
        <p><?php echo $row['nachricht']; ?></p>
                    <p><input class="button-link" type="submit" name="reply" value="Antworten"></form></p>
                    <p><form action="mailbox.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                        <input class="button-del" type="submit" name="delete_perm" style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 20px;" value="Löschen"></p></form>
```

why will the message not stay close by clicking close?

Comment: Can you please reformat the code? It's a little bit messy and you have to <script> tags that oppen but never close ...

Comment: thanks for answer me. i had trouble to find out how the codeinsertion works but now looks all formatted for me. the code is sperated from normal text

Answer (score 0):

i still haven't figured out what is wrong. if i use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('span.toggleOpen').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideDown("fast");
});
$('span.toggleClose').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.toggle').slideUp("fast");
});});
```

then it works, but i have to use two buttons (open and close) and both are always shown. what i want is one button that change the text by opening or close a message.